# Google Cloud End points

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

Is it possible expose and sell google cloud endpoint as an Api? I have created a simple but useful cloud endpoint. I want paid customers to access it directly as an api. How will I create a client-Id or API key dynamically for such clients, etc? For example, google also sells search service as API, where any user can go generate its own API key and Secret, and start using google search service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, no, or at least not without a lot of work.

The current product was designed with the "same party" use case as the primary goal (the API producer and consumer are the same). There are a number of things that would need to be added to the product to enable the kind of use you're describing. First and foremost on that list would be some kind of API consumer dashboard (like the one Google offers developers for consumers of its APIs).

Endpoints is built on the same API infrastructure as the rest of Google's APIs, and Google does offer this feature on some of its APIs. That may give you a sense of where the product is headed in future iterations.